# Jmeter - Distributed test - How to distribute users to multiple slaves

Tags: jmeter, unique, performance-testing, load-testing, distributed-testing

I am currently load testing login/logout function with max 2000 unique users and created a distributed test environment with  4 slaves and 1 master. We are able to successfully distribute traffic to all 4 slaves.

However, We do not want 4 slaves to use the same users during execution. We want to ensure each slave receive a unique set of test users in order to login to avoid any conflicts.

**Scenario:** 
- Distribute test max 2000 login sessions using 2000 unique users over 1 hour (gradual increase) 
- Master to distribute traffic to 4 slaves 
- Each slave to receive or use a unique set of users to execute the test. Therefore there should be no conflict between users.

(user distribution, 
Slave#1: Users 1 - 500 
Slave#2: user 501 - 1000 
slave#3: User 1001 - 1500 
Slave#4: user 1501 - 2000
)

Our Jmeter version is 3.3 (Windows PCs)

How do we achieve this? your help will be appreciated.

Thank you
Z

Answer (score 1):

1. JMeter slaves execute the [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) (.jmx script(s) which they receive from the Master so in order to have 2000 different users you should use `500` users in your [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) (given there is a single Thread Group, if there are more - correspondingly less)
2. If you use external data source, i.e. CSV file for storing user credentials you need to split it into 2 parts and upload them to remote slaves so they could be used by the [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config). An easier, unattended and scalable solution would be using [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) which has `KEEP` option, setting it to false will remove the credentials from the list therefore uniqueness will be guaranteed. You can install HTTP Simple Table Server plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.google.pl/search?q=blazemeter%20jemter%20plugins%20manager&oq=blazemeter%20jemter%20plugins%20manager&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.4080j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
3. According to [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to JMeter 4.0 (or whatever latest version is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) as soon as possible